# Setting up Sessions?

Tags: php

When a user logins into my site i set up a SESSION and there is one field in SESSION which is added:

```
Session::set('twostep', false);
```

if they have two step verification turned on and this wont allow them to access the site unless it says true so if they get the one time code from google authenticator app right it will be changed to true and let them use the site, is this a safe way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the Sessions are stored on the server and as long the server is not hacked there is no way to manipulate them, so (I would say) yes.
**Edit** of curse you can manipulate them as developer, or if you put some script which can be acessed by user and has the ability to do so.